# Remove Field Heading in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, field, heading

I have a crystal report designer problem:
In my report is a field I want to display. But I don't want the field heading to be displayed. How can I suppress this?

It looks like this:
**myFieldHeading**
FieldValue1
FieldValue2
FieldValue3

But I want just that:
FieldValue1
FieldValue2
FieldValue3

How can I do that?

bye juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. 
I found it. The header was added automatically in an other section. I removed it manually and now everything is fine.

Thanks anyway